# Copy last row field value to another column table with trigger

Tags: postgresql

I'm working in PostgreSQL using a trigger. I have 2 tables here, invoice_items and invoice. In the table 'invoice' data is inserted from the system, then the table 'invoice_items' is filled using a trigger to get the values from the inserted data of the table 'invoice'. Each insert from the system system consists of two rows like this:

table 'invoice':

```
id       invoice_date     statement  amount
 1        2018-10-03       Insert      5
 2        2018-10-03       Update      6
```

then table 'invoice_items' after trigger the invoice data is inserted:

```
id         total     statement
 1           5         Insert
 2           6         Update
```

trigger:

```
create trigger do_fetch
    after insert
    on invoices
    for each row
    execute procedure insert_amount();
```

function insert_amount():

```
create function insert_amount()
  returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO invoice_items (total, statement) VALUES (new.amount, new.statement);
return null;
END;

$$;
```

But I just want to get last inserted data of 'invoices' to trigger 'invoice_items' to achieve a result like this:

```
id       invoice_date     statement  amount
 1        2018-10-03       Insert      5
 2        2018-10-03       Update      6



id         total     statement
 1           6         Update
```

I have tried to edit the trigger to this:

```
create constraint trigger do_fetch
        after insert
        on invoices
        deferrable
        for each row
        execute procedure insert_amount();
```

but I still get 2 row inserted to 'invoice_items' table - not only the last row, any clue ? Thank you

Comment: You could adjust your trigger for each row where statement matches 'Update' ;) Syntax: [FOR [EACH] {ROW | STATEMENT}]

Comment: I'm use :  for each statement when (new.statement = 'Update' ) but it's syntax error, any clue ?

Comment: I've posted a solution for your issue - hope that will help you to solve your issue ;)

Comment: did you adjust your trigger and your function?

Comment: I spent time and effort to provide an answer to YOUR problem and edited my answer with the actual adjusted sql to your needs - the least you could do is to reply back..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example - you just need to adjust your sql with the desired tablenames and columnnames:

```
test=# create table bla1(ts timestamp, content text);
CREATE TABLE
test=*# create table bla1_log(ts timestamp, content text);
CREATE TABLE
test=*# create or replace function trg_bla1() returns trigger as $$begin insert into 
bla1_log values (new.ts, new.content); return new; end; $$language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
test=*# create trigger trg1 after insert on bla1 for each row when (NEW.content = 
'Update') execute procedure trg_bla1();
CREATE TRIGGER
test=*# insert into bla1 values (now(), 'bla');
INSERT 0 1
test=*# commit;
COMMIT
test=# insert into bla1 values (now(), 'Insert');
INSERT 0 1
test=*# commit;
COMMIT
test=# insert into bla1 values (now(), 'Update');
INSERT 0 1
test=*# select * from bla1;
```

> ts                          | content
>
> ----------------------------+---------
>
> 2018-11-08 12:32:28.803439 | bla
>
> 2018-11-08 12:33:30.355516 | Insert
>
> 2018-11-08 12:33:38.451548 | Update

(3 rows)

```
 test=*# select * from bla1_log ;
```

> ts                          | content
>
> ----------------------------+---------
>
> 2018-11-08 12:33:38.451548 | Update

(1 row)

```
 test=*#
```

**EDIT:**

As of your lack of replies and showing an effort to adjust your code according to my answer, I'm not sure if thats even worth my time - but here's what should work for you..

```
 create table invoice(id serial, invoice_date text, statement text, amount integer);


 create table invoice_items(id serial, total integer, statement text);


 create or replace function insert_amount() returns trigger as $$begin 
 insert into invoice_items values (id, total, statement); return new; end; 


 create trigger mytrigger after insert on invoice for each row when (NEW.statement = 'Update') execute procedure insert_amount();
```

Comment: i try with last line :  create trigger mytrigger after insert on invoice for each row when (NEW.statement = 'Update') execute procedure insert_amount();
finally got work, thank you :)

Comment: @Lazar : Then please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and upvote it - thanks ;)